# Optimum Volume and Surface Area Grade 9

Tags: word-problem

Two shapes both have a surface are of 1200cm2. One of them is a cylinder and one of them is a square based prism.

a) What is the maximum value of the volume of the shape if it is a cylinder?

b) What is the maximum value of the volume of the shape if it is a square based prism?

c) Which shape should you chose for a container you are building if you want the greatest possible volume and the least possible surface are?

Answer (score 0):

The area and volume of a cylinder are respectively
$$ A_{cylinder} = 2\pi r h + 2\pi r^2 \quad V_{cylinder} = \pi r^2 h $$
Where $r$ denotes the radius of the cylinder and $h$ denotes the height of the cylinder.
Since we know that $A_{cylinder} = 1200$ we can express $h$ in terms or $r$
$$ h = \frac{A_{cylinder} - 2\pi r^2}{2\pi r} $$
Now let's use this to find an expression for the volume in terms of the surface area.
$$ V_{cylinder} = \pi r^2 \frac{A_{cylinder} - 2\pi r^2}{2\pi r} = \frac{A_{cylinder}r-2\pi r^3}{2}$$
To find the maximum value we differentiate this expression and set it equal to zero.
$$ \frac{dV_{cylinder}}{dr} = \frac{A_{cylinder}}{2}-6\pi r^2 = 0 $$
Thus we conclude that $r^2 = \frac{A_{cylinder}}{12\pi}$ and thus $r = \sqrt{\frac{A_{cylinder}}{12\pi}}$ since the radus cannot be negative. Putting it all together yields
$$ V_{cylinder} = \frac{5A_{cylinder}}{6}\sqrt{\frac{A_{cylinder}}{12\pi}} = \frac{10000}{\sqrt{\pi}} cm^3$$

Comment: Try to do the prism in the same way. Let me know if you managed to do it!:)